# Ошибка подключения к БД в dbeaver. Can't initialize tunnelCannot establish tunnel to www.footballfacts.ru:22Exhausted available authentication methods

Tags: dbeaver

у меня есть удаленная база данных mysql. Всегда работал в phpmyadmin. Решил перейти на dbeaver. Подключаю таким образом
[image: подключение первым способом]

Получаю ошибку

[image: ошибка подключения].

Пробую через ssh

[image: подключение по ssh]
и снова ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

логи из dbeaver

```
!ENTRY org.jkiss.dbeaver.model 4 0 2023-05-06 18:55:02.744
!MESSAGE Cannot establish tunnel to www.sites.ru:22
!SUBENTRY 1 org.jkiss.dbeaver.model 4 0 2023-05-06 18:55:02.744
!MESSAGE Cannot establish tunnel to www.sites.ru:22
!SUBENTRY 2 org.jkiss.dbeaver.model 4 0 2023-05-06 18:55:02.744
!MESSAGE Exhausted available authentication methods
!STACK 0
net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.UserAuthException: Exhausted available authentication methods
at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.auth(SSHClient.java:230)
at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.auth(SSHClient.java:205)
at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.authPassword(SSHClient.java:291)
at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.authPassword(SSHClient.java:261)
at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.authPassword(SSHClient.java:245)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.net.ssh.SSHImplementationSshj.setupTunnel(SSHImplementationSshj.java:106)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.net.ssh.SSHImplementationAbstract.initTunnel(SSHImplementationAbstract.java:134)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.net.ssh.SSHTunnelImpl.initializeHandler(SSHTunnelImpl.java:77)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.registry.DataSourceDescriptor.connect(DataSourceDescriptor.java:1044)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.jobs.ConnectJob.run(ConnectJob.java:70)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.jobs.ConnectJob.runSync(ConnectJob.java:98)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.actions.datasource.DataSourceHandler.connectToDataSource(DataSourceHandler.java:109)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.actions.datasource.UIServiceConnectionsImpl.initConnection(UIServiceConnectionsImpl.java:87)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.navigator.DBNDataSource.initializeNode(DBNDataSource.java:158)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.navigator.DBNDatabaseNode.getChildren(DBNDatabaseNode.java:225)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.navigator.DBNDatabaseNode.getChildren(DBNDatabaseNode.java:1)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.navigator.DBNUtils.getNodeChildrenFiltered(DBNUtils.java:80)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.navigator.database.load.TreeLoadService.evaluate(TreeLoadService.java:49)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.navigator.database.load.TreeLoadService.evaluate(TreeLoadService.java:1)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.LoadingJob.run(LoadingJob.java:88)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.LoadingJob.run(LoadingJob.java:72)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Логин и пароль от бд работают в phpmyadmin, доступ по ssh работает в консоли. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно подключиться?